# Symfony2+Twig - Using TwigBundle's path() in my own filter

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm trying to create a Twig extension for my project. The goal is to generate a user popup with the jquery.cluetip plugin, which can display the result of an AJAX query in a nice tooltip. The HTML code generated should look like this:

```
<span class="userdata" rel="/profile/123/ajaxUserdata.html">W00d5t0ck</span>
```

Currently, my code looks like this:

```
class UserDataSpanExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{                       
    protected $_securityContext;

    public function __construct(SecurityContextInterface $security)
    {
        $this->_securityContext = $security;
    }

    public function getFilters()
    {
        return array(
            'userdataspan' => new \Twig_Filter_Method($this, 'getUserDataSpan', array('is_safe' => array('html'))),
        );
    }

    public function getUserDataSpan(User $user)
    {
        if (!is_object($this->_securityContext->getToken()) || !is_object($this->_securityContext->getToken()->getUser()))
            return '<span class="userdata-secret" title="|User information|User information is available only to logged in users.">[not available]</span>';

        return '<span class="userdata" rel="">' . $user->getDisplayName() . '</span>';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
            return 'twig_userdataspan';
    }
}
```

Now I'm a bit stuck as I don't know how should I fill my `rel` attribute. In a Twig template I would use

```
{{ path('AcmeDemoBundle_ajaxUserdata', { id: user.id }) }}
```

but this won't work in a Twig extension. Could anyone point me at a usable example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inject the `router` in your twig extension service and generate url in usual way in your method, e.g

```
$this->router->generate('AcmeDemoBundle_ajaxUserdata', array(
    'id' => $user->id,
));
```

Add @router argument to your extension in services.yml:

```
services:
    demo.twig.extension:
        class: DemoBundle\Twig\Extension
        arguments: [@router]
```